# How can I tell if a Nancy request is mobile

Tags: nancy

I am trying to figure out the best way to tell if a request in NancyFx is a mobile request. I assume I should use the user-agent, but I didn't know if there was a `better` solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably right. I don't think there is a better solution.
But there is debate about how it should be done.

This thread is useful:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nancy-web-framework/8MsU4zh2pN8